# version tolerant serialization with mongo db objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, serialization, bson

I am a .net c# developer and I am currently exploring integration with a mongo db database. This database will be the backend to a mvc database.

CRUD operation will be performed on the database from the MVC application to the mongo db and also data will be inserted in to it from a simple console application that parses xml files and inserts/updates the database in to the mongo db.

I have been reviewing the C Sharp Mongo Db driver and have a question around object serliazation and the relation to strongly typed objects etc. What I am not very clear on is if I have an object to reflects the structure of a mongo bson document. This object gets serialized in to the mongo db document. Questions I have around this are:

- What if there is a new release of my application, increment of the dll version number. Following the release, can the original data be serialized in to the new version of the object? Or does my object need to be version tolerant?
- If my console application inserts in the data and the mvc application performs CRUD operations on the same bson document, does it need to share the same object between both applications? I would prefer to avoid this dependency if possible so what is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the section in the serialization tutorial related to versioning here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-HandlingSchemaChanges.

1) To answer your first question, you object definitely needs to be version tolerant.

2) They don't need to share the same object as long as the mapping is the same.  That means the same structure, same attributes, and same conventions.

That being said, sharing the same data object is not the end of the world.  And you wouldn't be creating a dependency between the two systems.  Instead, you would create a shared library that contains the object and the code necessary to persist the data.  Then, you don't need to replicate code between the two different mediums.  Think of the shared library as an API.

An alternative would be for the console application to call the MVC application to upload the data.  The MVC app becomes an API not only for users to interact with but also for programs.  Again, logic in one place.